Which Timber LOK screws to reinforce shallow ridge, and how many?
I bought a tiny house shell that still needs some rafter reinforcement. I have chevron-shaped gussets from 1/2'' plywood that I'm going to glue and nail on either side of the middle gambrel joint on either side. For the ridge, I was thinking of driving one or more Timber LOK into the end of each rafter from the other side of the ridge beam. I might also use some shear strap to cross the bottom of the ridge joint.
Which Timber LOK screw should I use? What size? Do you recommend one or multiple?

https://issuu.com/fastenmaster/docs/fmfullcat_july_06-2023_pages
Note: I acknowledge that you are not giving engineering advice and have no liability in this. I am just asking for your ideas
Note: Cross-posted at: https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebuilding/comments/1e512x2/which_timber_lok_screws_to_reinforce_shallow/

we'll wait for answers on reddit ... might as well not waste time  making duplicate effort

Whatever. If I saw this and had an answer, I'd post it. I assume others follow the golden rule.

the golden rule is do not crosspost

@jsotola -- Stated where? Cross-postibg between StackExchange communities is generally discouraged but not forbidden (see). I did find this and this and this.
